# Debug jumping lines after file dialog code

Tags: excel, vba

Is this a known bug, or something specific to me (I'm using Excel 365).

When I skip to the next line (F8) of code after a file dialog show call (selecting a folder or cancelling) it seems to turn off single stepping and runs all the code to either the next breakpoint or resumes if there is no code.

In the sample below I single step code, it gets to 'fd.show' then as soon as I select a folder/cancel and click ok it just runs the code.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim n As Integer

    n = 0
    sFile = "Work_" & Replace(Date, "/", "") & Replace(Time, ":", "") & ".csv"

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    '*********** SINGLE STEP AFTER SHOW RUNS TO END *******************      
    If fd.Show = -1 Then
        Dim sDir As String
        sDir = fd.SelectedItems.Item(1)

        If Dir(sFile) = "" Then
            n = 1
        Else
            n = 2
        End If

    End If

    MsgBox CStr(n)
End Sub
```

Comment: `If fd.Show = -1 Then` it would (normally) act exactly how you describes if `fd.Show = -1`... Otherwise, it goes inside the loop. Did you select a folder?

Comment: no, I mean no matter what happens single step is disabled, I can remove the if statement and have a dozen lines and it still jumps out of single step mode.

Comment: Do you use a 32 bit Office version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to **F8 Key Stops Working when debugging** has been described on [contextures](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2014/09/04/excel-vba-problem-with-step-into-f8/), in detail [here](https://www.contextures.com/excelvbatips.html#f8)

Essentially you have to add a new key -  a DWORD with the name **DisableOrpcDebugging7** - to the registry and change its value to **1**.

- For **32-bit Office on 64-bit Window** go to registry key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VBA
- For **32-bit Office on 32-bit Window** go to registry key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\ Microsoft\VBA
- For **64-bit Office on 64-bit Windows** go to registry key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\ Microsoft\VBA

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I did google a lot to see if it was a known issue.